# How do you use react-router-dom to redirect user when token has expired?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-router-dom

I have a React application that accesses a Flask API. To access some API routes, the user needs to log in. I am using Axios to do the requests. Then, he receives a token which is stored in the local storage. When this token expires and the user makes another request, I want to **redirect him to the login page**. However, I don't know how I would do it.

I am treating API request errors with **Axios response interceptor**. It removes the token from the local storage and then should redirect the user to the login page. Since I am using **functional components**, I could not find an example that fits well (besides downloading another package called history).

I have tried to use the 'useHistory' hook and Redirect from react-router-dom (with a proper BrowserRouter set up), but it doesn't work.

**api.js**

```
import axios from "axios"

import { RemoveAuth } from "./Auth"

export const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/api/",
    timeout: 15000,
})

// more code

api.interceptors.response.use(null, (error) => {

  if(error.response.status === 401){
    RemoveAuth();
  }

  return error;
});
```

**Auth.js**

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"

export const RemoveAuth = () => {
  let history = useHistory()
  localStorage.clear();
  history.push('/login')
}
```

**routes.js**

```
import React from "react";

import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import PrivateRoutes from "./PrivateRoutes";


import Dashboard from "../pages/dashboard";

import Login from "../pages/login";
import Logout from "../pages/logout";

const Routes = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <PrivateRoutes exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <PrivateRoutes exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

**PrivateRoutes.js**

```
import React from "react";

import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import { AuthLogin } from "../services/Auth";

const PrivateRoutes = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={() => (AuthLogin() ? <Redirect to="/login" /> : <Component />)}
    />
);

export default PrivateRoutes;
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I think you can only use 'useHistory' in react component. in Auth.js you can handle it by 'window.location.reload()'. after that automatically detecte in PrivateRoute and redirected to /login

Comment: @navand this works perfectly! It is a much simpler solution than installing another package. It would add more complexity to the code. Is there any downside to doing this?

Comment: For another way you should handle it from react component that called api.

Comment: Yeah, there's no other way around it, right? If you want to write an answer with what you said in the first comment, I'll be glad to mark it as the correct answer!

Comment: Note, `window.location.reload` causes the entire page to refresh.  It is just like hitting the refresh button in your browser.  Very different from `react-router` solution.

Comment: @jack.benson this is true! But it kinda works. I saw that history is a package from react-router-dom (my bad), so this should be the right way to go. I still don't understand what is the advantage to set up an extra file. Is there any or would `window.location.reload()` be ok for this case?

Comment: You don't necessarily need an extra file, but you need to export history from somewhere so you have access to it when you create your `Router` and then again when you need to reference your history directly.

Comment: @jack.benson well, your answer seems to be the most general one. Thanks for the patience and effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to create your own history object.  Something like this:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();
export default history;
```

Then in your provider pass in your custom history object:

```
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import history from './utils/history'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <App />
  </Router>
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This allows you to utilize your history in non-component code.  Just import your history object into your `Auth.js` file and use it:

```
import { history } from './utils/history'

export const RemoveAuth = () => {
  localStorage.clear();
  history.push('/login')
}
```

As an added bonus, now your history lives in a place that is easily mock-able, so creating testing around it is more straightforward.  You can find more information about creating your own custom history object [in the docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md).

Comment: @jack-benson thanks for the answer! I was trying to look for a solution that did not require another package to be installed. Shouldn't react-router-dom take care of this? Do react-router-dom and history have different responsibilities?

Comment: You don't have to explicitly install it, as it is already in your `node_modules`.  It is a core dependency of `react-router-dom`.