# How to redirect to login page if the session expires in asp.net core + React application

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, session, routes

I have an ASP.NET Core + React web application. All the routing happens in React application.

I want to use ActionFilterAttribute to check if the session is expired. How do I redirect to the login screen if I do not use controller/action?

[SessionTimeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpkst.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [don't upload code, results or data as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

for achieve this instead of try to redirect user to login page with you back just return 403 status code into your front-end then depends on your fetch library in front-end like Axios or something like that try to write some interceptor code and redirect all 401 status code into login page.

[you can see Axios interceptor example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66108993/how-do-you-use-react-router-dom-to-redirect-user-when-token-has-expired)

this approach is more efficient because somethings front-end login page have different routes or even login can be a modal also as a back-end you will be service for multi front-end or mobile application so just return correct status code as response and let front-end make chose to what to do whit code.

[List of reserve status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)